# A succinct binary tree of sums, array construction and addressing

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, go, tree

Using 'sum' as a short hand for some arbitrary computation. I have a process that computes a single sum from a list of values by recursively summing pairs of values. Un-paired values are promoted up the tree unaltered until they can be paired.

Given this computation, I'm in search of the best way to balance computation (i.e. number of operation required to access array elements/nodes), and the most succinct encoding of all nodes in a 1 dimensional array (i.e. no gaps, nil values, or repeated values), and preferably without an additional index array that cannot be easily derived from the succinct encoding so that it would have to be saved along with the array.

Although the following are simple examples, in reality the number of values in the initial list can be extraordinarily large (2^47 or more).

For example, given the list [1, 2, 3, 4], the array is trivial: [10, 3, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4], and split nicely into rows that are easy to address by node, or as a reference to the entire row.

But for a 5 item list the tree looks like this:

#### Tree 1

```
         15
        /  \
       /    \
      /      \
     /        \
    10          5
  /   \       /   \
 3     7     5     -
/ \   / \   / \   / \
1  2  3  4 5   - -   -
```

The standard mapping `left = i*2+1`, `right = i*2+2` gives us this array:

#### Array 1

```
[ 15, 10,  5,  3,   7,   5,  nil,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   nil,   nil, nil]
```

This array has 4 nil values, and the last element in the list '5' is repeated 2 times.

To improve this we can imply the repetition of the 5, and remove the nil values:

#### Array 2

```
[15, 10, 3, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Which is much more compact. This tree is the same, but conceptually looks a bit like:

#### Tree 2

```
       15
      / \
     /   \
    10    \
  /   \    \
 3     7    \
/ \   / \    \
1  2  3  4    5
```

In the **Array 2** encoding I have 4 rows:

```
1. [1, 2, 3, 4]
2. [3, 7]
3. [10, 5]
4. [15]
```

Rows 1, 2 and 4 can simply be references into **Array 2** allowing me to compute results 'in-place' with no allocations or copies. Very fast. Row 3 however, contains values in two non-contiguous cells. I have to break the simple logic used for the other rows, and possibly add copy, indexing or storage for a map.

I can construct complete/balanced sub trees (such as indexes 1-7, the tree for 1, 2, 3, 4), but it seems like they will not always be so nicely aligned when the odd number of items appears at different rows depending on input length.  For example consider a tree with an initial list of 6 elements.

Comment: Shouldn't your example tree have in-order `1 3 2 10 3 7 4 15 5 5 5`, since a single child value is propagated to its parent? Furthermore, if `-` represents an empty node, your tree can be defined from the bottom up, level by level, as `1 2 3 4 5 - - -`, `3 7 5 -`, `10 5`, `5`. That order also represents a good logic for the implementation; if you keep each level in an array, the calculation to get the next level has all arguments consecutive in memory. In the file, you could save the nodes level by level, as `5`, `10 5`, `3 7 5 -`, `1 2 3 4 5 - - -`.

Comment: Yes your in-order traversal is correct.  My array is an example solution, not a traversal.  I'll make this more clear. You are thinking in the same direction as I am with respect addressing entire rows at a time.  However, if I understand you then your solution still "wastes space proportional to 2h - n" (wikipedia), like a typical binary tree array.  The point here is I'm trying to do better, no empty nodes, no repeated values.

Comment: If you consider each level in the tree a list, do you always merge consecutive members in the list, propagating the possible leftover member up to the next level? If you do, then you only need to store the number of nodes in the lowest level, and then the nodes in each level from left to right. The tree structure is then well defined (except for whether single child nodes hang off the left or the right member of the parent node).

Comment: Yes, that is correct, and if I allow copying (as apposed to writing into the pre-allocated final array) then it is easy to implement but costs a minimum of one allocation per row and a copy for every array element.  Also not bing top down addressable kind of kills any value of it being a tree, no?

Comment: 1) You only have a few dozen levels in your tree (on current 64-bit machines, at most 65) because your trees with `n` levels have at least `2**(n-1)+n-1` nodes total (at least `2**(k-1)+1` nodes on level `k`). An operation per level is insignificant overhead. 2) If a level has an odd number of nodes, and the final node is propagated up as-is, as the left child of the parent node if the parent node has no other children, the number of nodes on the most numerous level, defines the entire shape of the tree. Knowing this number, you can traverse the tree normally.

Comment: 3) If we know the number of elements on the most numerous level, we can treat the entire tree as one linear array. Since each level has at most one odd element that is propagated upwards, this means at most one element copied per level. In summary, the only thing that would be needed, is the number of nodes on the most numerous level, for one to treat the linear array as a tree. None of the "unused nodes" (compared to a binary tree) are stored or reserved in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your tree has `N` nodes on the final (most numerous) row.

If you do store the nodes that are only propagated upwards, your tree has between `2*N-1` and `2*N-1+log2(N)` nodes, total. The exact total number of nodes is given by [OEIS A120511](http://oeis.org/A120511). Of these, at most `floor(2 + log2(N-1))` are copied/propagated nodes.

The tree has `floor(2 + log2(N-1))` rows. The number of rows as a function of  `N` (the number of elements on the final row) is [OEIS A070941](http://oeis.org/A070941).

The number of rows in such trees is quite low. For example, if you have 2<sup>40</sup> ≈ 1,000,000,000,000 nodes in the final row, you only have 42 rows in the tree. For 2<sup>64</sup> nodes, you have just 66. Therefore, if you need some operation per row, it is not a high overhead.

A simple logarithmic-time function can compute the number of rows and the total number of nodes, given the number of nodes in the final row `N`:

```
# Account for the root node
rows = 1
total = 1

curr_left = N
While (curr_left > 1):
    rows = rows + 1
    total = total + curr_left
    curr_left = (curr_left + 1) / 2
End While
```

where `/` denotes integer division, i.e. any fractional part is discarded/truncated/rounded towards zero. Again, for 2<sup>64</sup> nodes in the final row, the above loops only 65 times.

When we know the total number of nodes in the tree, and the number of rows, we can use another logarithmic-time loop to compute the offset of the first element on each row of the tree, and the number of nodes on that row:

```
first_offset = []
nodes = []

curr_row = rows - 1
curr_offset = total - N
curr_left = N

While (curr_left > 1):
    nodes[curr_row] = curr_left
    first_offset[curr_row] = curr_offset
    curr_row = curr_row - 1
    curr_left = (curr_left + 1) / 2
    curr_offset = curr_offset - curr_left
}

first_offset[0] = 0
nodes[0] = 1
```

As before, for 2<sup>64</sup> nodes in the final row, the above loops only 65 times.

All elements on a row are consecutive in memory, and if we use zero-based indexing, and `N` is the number of nodes on the final row, and we apply the above, then

- `rows` is the number of rows in the tree
- `total` is the total number of nodes in the tree
- There are `nodes[r]` nodes on row `r`, if `r >= 0` and `r < rows`
- Array index for node on row `r`, column `c` is `first_offset[r] + c`
- Node on row `r`, column `c`, with `r > 0`, has a parent on row `r-1`, column `c/2`, at array index `first_offset[r-1] + c/2`
- Node on row `r`, column `c`, with `r < rows - 1`, has a left child on row `r+1`, column `2*c`, at array index `first_offset[r+1] + 2*c`
- Node on row `r`, column `c`, with `r < rows - 1` and `c < nodes[r] - 1`, has a right child on row `r+1`, column `2*c+1`, at array index `first_offset[r+1] + 2*c + 1`
- Node on row `r`, column `c`, with `r < rows - 1` and `c < nodes[r] - 1`, has both a left and a right child

This array is compact, and other than the nodes that get propagated upwards (so, maybe a few dozen nodes for a terabyte-sized dataset), wastes no storage.

If the number of nodes in the final row is stored with the array (for example, as an extra `uint64_t` following the array data), all readers can recover `total`, `rows`, `first_offset[]`, and `nodes[]`, and easily navigate the tree. (However, note that instead of just the array index, you use the "column" and "row" instead, and derive the array index using those.)

Because `first_offset[]` and `nodes[]` arrays have at most a few dozen entries, they should stay hot in caches, and using them should not harm performance.

Note that not all tree sizes are valid for the rules stated in the second paragraph above. For example, a tree with two nodes makes no sense: why would you duplicate the root node?

If you do know that the tree size (`total`) is valid, you can find `N` based on `total` in `O(log2(total)*log2log2(total))` time complexity using a binary search, or in `O((log2(total))²)` if you use a simple loop. Remember, `total` is between `2*N-1` and `2*N-1+log2(N)`. Conversely, `N` cannot be greater than `(N + 1)/2`, or smaller than `(N + 1)/2 - log2(total)`, because `total` is greater than `N`, and therefore `log2(N)` is less than `log2(total)`. So, a binary search could be implemented as

```
Function Find_N(total):
    Nmax = (total + 1) / 2
    Nmin = Nmax - log2(total)

    t = Total(Nmin)
    If t == total:
        Return Nmin
    Else if t < total:
        Return "Bug!"
    End if

    t = Total(Nmax)
    if t == total:
        Return Nmax
    Else if t > total:
        Return "Bug!"
    End if

    Loop:

        N = (Nmin + Nmax) / 2
        If N == Nmin:
            Return "Invalid tree size!"
        End If

        t = Total(N)
        If t > total:
            Nmax = N
        Else if t < total:
            Nmin = N
        Else:
            return N
        End If            
    End Loop
End Function
```

Keep in mind that even with 2<sup>64</sup> nodes in the tree, the above function makes at most `1 + log2(64)` = 6 calls to `Total`, a function implementing the first pseudocode snippet in this answer. Since you typically need this only once per program invocation, the overhead is truly irrelevant.

You can calculate `log2(x)` using `log(x)/log(2)`, using the `log2()` function from `<math.h>` since C99 (but since `double` has less precision than `uint64_t`, I would add `+1` to the result, or round it towards positive infinity using `ceil()`, just to be sure), or even using a simple loop:

```
Function ulog2(value):
    result = 0
    While (value > 0):
        result = result + 1
        value = value / 2
    End While
    Return result
End Function
```

where once again, `/` denotes integer division.

Comment: Great answer, well presented. Of course trying to remove an O(log n) duplication was a frivolous optimization. Simply leaving them in makes this all very easy. I think I can figure it out, but do you have any suggestions for finding `N` from `total` for imperfect trees? (P.S. there's a small typo / inconsistency between your `while` loops)

Comment: @JoshuaKolden: Not all `total` are valid given the rules for the tree, but for those that are valid, I added a binary search. (It does less than 7 iterations for 2⁶⁴nodes, and fewer for smaller trees, so it is definitely efficient enough.) Also, I removed the inconsistency for clarity, but either way, the loops have (and had) the same number of iterations.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work either.  An `N` of 17 has a `total` of 37, but `(37-1)/2 = 18`, perhaps it should be `Nmin = (total - log2(total)) / 2`?

Comment: @JoshuaKolden: Whoops, I made a double-bug there. Should be fixed now. Let me explain. We have `T >= 2*N-1` and `T <= 2*N-1+log2(N)`. If we solve for `N`, the lower limit gives us the upper limit for `N`, `N <= (T + 1)/2`. The upper limit for `T` gives us the lower limit for `N`, `N >= W(log(2)*2**(T+2)) / (2*log(2))` where `W(x*exp(x)) = x` for all positive `x`. I am still verifying that `W(log(2)*2**(T+2))/(2*log(2)) >= (T + 1)/2 - log2(T)`, but random testing on 62-bit `N` (so `T` does not overflow) says this works.

Comment: @JoshuaKolden: `Nmax = (T + 1)/2`, `Nmin = Nmax - log2(T)` should be correct. The ratio of `(T + 1)/2 - log(T)/log(2)` and `W(log(2)*2**(T+2))/(2*log(2))` is 1 at `T == 1`, the limit of the ratio at `T` towards infinity is 1; and the ratio is less than 1 in between, according to Maple, so these limits should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking for a succinct encoding of a binary tree.  For this it's sufficient to store the node data in pre-order with one additional bit to denote leaf vs internal node. The algorithms for encoding and decoding are rather simple and given in [a Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Succinct_encodings), so I won't repeat them here. This encoding is very close to the information-theoretic best possible. It's probably not worth looking for a better one.

Comment: Thank you, but the succinct binary tree encoding discussed is capable of encoding binary trees of arbitrary structure.  My binary tree is more constrained so shouldn't need this information for every node.  For example for n > 3 there is always one or more complete & balanced binary trees of at most height-1 on the lower left hand side of the larger tree as in the subtree for 1-4 within the tree for 1-5 above.

Comment: @JoshuaKolden Well then you should say that in the question. You said you'd like to balance computations, but never that balance was guaranteed. There's nothing about expression trees that gives them structure beyond the fact that all internal nodes have 2 children.